# Create 4 MB (not GB) partition on memory card

Tags: partitioning, windows-11, memory-card

I have a very old piece of equipment that requires a 4 MB (not GB) PCMCIA card. Those aren't available any more. So I bought a PCMCIA adapter with a CF card. I am trying to create a 4 MB partition, in hopes that that will fool my old equipment.

When I go into Windows 11 Disk Management, it won't allow me to create a volume of less than 8 MB. Is it possible to create an (unformatted) 4 MB partition somehow?

Comment: Use a third-party disk management tool. Software recommendations are out of scope though

Comment: Even the third party tool I used could not create a partition below a minimum of 8 MB. I'm wondering if there is some technical limitation with the partitioning metadata?

Comment: There might be. How did you determine it requires 4MB partition?

Comment: There isn't such limitation with the legendary (Linux) GParted or anything else, GUI or command line tools, in Linux. Otherwise people intending to install their distros in Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode in GPT drives wouldn't be able to create the unformatted 1 or 2MB `bios_grub` partition :). That said, as above, *how did you determine it requires 4MB partition?*

Comment: Using Windows 10 or 11 I routinely do stuff like this using Gparted on Debian in VMWare Player, having connected the USB card reader to the VM.

Comment: I determined I need 4MB two ways: Documentation for my hardware device says so, and when I plug in a 64MB CF it doesn't recognize it. It's an old device, and there's always a chance it's simply broken, but I want to try to create a 4MB partition to see if I can get that to work. I'll try Gparted with my Ubuntu Linux boot image.